# Как path отправляет второй параметр

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте!

Имеется:

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'topics/<topic_id>', views.topic, name='topic')
]
```

**view.py**

```
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """ Выводит одну тему и все ее записи """

    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}

    return render(request=request,
                  template_name='learning_logs/topic.html',
                  context=context)
```

Не могу понять, каким образом `path` отправляет `topic_id` во `view.topic`?

Answer (score 2):

`path` ничего не отправляет. Эта функция только возвращает `URLResolver` на этапе загрузки кода проекта при старте сервера. Если упрощённо, то когда Django принимает http-запрос, `WSGIHandler` обходит в цикле список `urlpatterns`, сравнивая по очереди URL запроса и паттерн каждого URLResolver'а. Когда обнаруживается наиболее подходящий, он извлекает из запроса параметры, в соответствии с паттерном, и вызывает соответствующее представление с этими параметрами.

Comment: Кажется, я осознал. То, что находится в угловых скобках и есть тот самый второй параметр topic_id.

Comment: Ага, это он и есть.